# Saving CF7 extension plugin "Images Optimize and Upload CF7" image data into ACF image field of CPT

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

We have created a form with cf7 and created image field with "Images Optimize and Upload CF7" plugin and now we want to save the each filed data to cpt but could not save cf7 image into acf image field of that particular cpt here is my code:

```
function save_posted_data( $posted_data ) {


       $args = array(
         'post_type' => 'prescriptions',
         'post_status'=>'draft',
         'post_title'=>$posted_data['phonenumber'],
       );
       $post_id = wp_insert_post($args);

       if(!is_wp_error($post_id)){
         if( isset($posted_data['location']) ){
           update_post_meta($post_id, 'location', $posted_data['location']);
         }
         if( isset($posted_data['phonenumber']) ){
           update_post_meta($post_id, 'contact_number', $posted_data['phonenumber']);
         }

         if( isset($posted_data['prescriptiontext']) ){
           update_post_meta($post_id, 'prescription_description', $posted_data['prescriptiontext']);
         }

         if ( !function_exists('wp_handle_upload') ) {
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
}

// Move file to media library
$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES[$posted_data['prescriptionimage']], array('test_form' => false) );

// If move was successful, insert WordPress attachment
if ( $movefile && !isset($movefile['error']) ) {
$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$attachment = array(
'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($movefile['file']),
'post_mime_type' => $movefile['type'],
'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', "", basename($movefile['file']) ),
'post_content' => "",
'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $movefile['file']);
update_field('prescription_image', $attach_id, $post_id);

}
      //and so on ...
      return $posted_data;
     }
 }

add_filter( 'wpcf7_posted_data', 'save_posted_data' );
```

This is my code and $posted_data['prescriptionimage'] is the image field name in cf7 and image saved as 1191566397/ID_file_download.png like this.We didnt know what's wrong in the code could anyone help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a snippet of code that might help you.  Without me actually answering your question specifically, I believe this will point you in the right direction.  You shouldn't hook `wpcf7_posted_data` but rather hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail` where you can receive the posted data. In my case, I added an attachment, and included the author metadata.  But I believe with this, you can figure out how to append to your ACF Field? I made `$posted_data` return what you have above.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'he_cf7_process_form', 10, 1);
/**
 * @param object $contact_form The UserID of the Poster
 */
function he_cf7_process_form($contact_form) {
    // check to make sure it only fires on your contact form
    if ( $contact_form->id() == integer_of_your_contact_form ) return;

    // Get the contact form submitted data
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ($submission) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        $uploaded_files = $submission->uploaded_files();
    } else {
        return;
    }
    // Your field name of the file goes here
    $files = $_FILES['field-name'];

    if (empty($uploaded_files)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        $image_name = basename($uploaded_files['field-name']);
        $image_location = $uploaded_files['field-name'];
        $image_content = file_get_contents($image_location);

        $wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        $upload = wp_upload_bits($image_name, null, $image_content);

        $filename = $upload['file'];

        $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $wp_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename($filename),
            'post_mime_type' => $files['type'],
            'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
        );

        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename);

        // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

        // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);

        $arg = array(
            'ID' => $attach_id,
            'post_author' => $userid,
        );

        wp_update_post($arg);
        
    }
}
```